# C++ member function pointers in class and subclass

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, function-pointers

I have one base class which holds a `map` for function pointers like this

```
typedef void (BaseClass::*event_t)();
class BaseClass {
    protected:
        std::map<std::string, event_t> events;
    public:
        // Example event
        void onFoo() {
            // can be added easily to the map
        }
};
```

Handling this works prefect, but now i want to make `BaseClass` an abstract base class to derive from like this:

```
 class SpecificClass : public BaseClass {
     public:
         void onBar() {
             // this is gonna be difficult!
         }
 };
```

Although i can access the map from `SpecificClass` i am not able to add `onBar` because the `event_t` type is only defined for the `BaseClass`! Is there any possibility (maybe with templates?) which does not lead to define the `event_t` for each class i will use...

(It is not neccessary to use templates! Any good/suitable approach would be nice.)

More background information:

This whole thing is for a text based RPG. My base class could be called `Location` and the specifc one any location e.g. `CivicCenter`. Each `Location` object subscribes to my `EventSystem` which notifies all neccessary objects when i fire an event. Therefore i want to store in a map some pointers to private functions holding the actions with their "name" like `onSetOnFire` (xD) as the key.

Comment: @Griwes: This has nothing to do with templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some thought and a redesign i was able to achieve what i wanted. Although i am stubborn and still using inheritance i have reimplemented the map. This is how it works now:

```
class Location {
    // ...

    protected:
        std::map<std::string, std::function<void(void)>> m_mEvents;
};
```

And now i can handle it like this:

```
class CivicCenter : public Location {
    public:
        CivicCenter() {
            // this is done by a macro which lookes better than this
            this->m_mEvents["onTriggerSomething"] =
                  std::bind(&CivicCenter::onTriggerSomething, this);
        }

        void onTriggerSomething() {
            // ...
        }

    // ...
};
```

With easy use of `std::bind` i am able to implement generic function pointers. When using parameters like in `std::function<void(int, int)>` remeber to use either boost's `_1` and `_2` or lambda expressions like me:

```
std::function<void(int,int)> f = [=](int a, int b) {
    this->anotherFunctionWithParams(a, b);
};
```

But this is just pointed out due to completeness of my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `static_cast`:

```
event_t evt = static_cast<event_t>(&SpecificClass::onBar);
```

This is because it is slightly dangerous to cast to `event_t`, you could accidently apply it to a `BaseClass` instance.

**How it works (for the skeptical):**

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    typedef void (BaseClass::*callback_t)(); // callback method
    void doSomething(callback_t callback) {
        // some code
        this->*callback();
        // more code
    }
    void baseCallback(); // an example callback
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    void derivedCallback();
    void doWhatever() {
        // some code
        doSomething(&BaseClass::baseCallback);
        // more code
        doSomething(static_cast<callback_t>(&DerivedClass::derivedCallback));
        // et cetera
};
```

Here is what you should **avoid,** and why this is potentially dangerous:

```
void badCodeThatYouShouldNeverWrite()
{
    BaseClass x;
    // DO NOT DO THIS IT IS BAD
    x.doSomething(static_cast<callback_t>(&DerivedClass::derivedCallback));
}
```

The requirement for a `static_cast` makes it so you can't "accidentally" pass `DerivedClass` method pointers in.  And if you think this is dangerous, just remember that it's a pointer, and pointers are always dangerous.  Of course, there are ways you can do this that involve creating helper classes, but that requires a lot of extra code (possibly making a class for every function you want to pass as a callback).  Or you could use closures in C++11, or something from Boost, but I realize that a lot of us do not have that option.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not legal C++. I'm not certain, but I don't think you can cast member pointers like that, nor can you later call them through the base class, unless the member is _in_ the base class.

Comment: Even I think, it's not legal C++.

Comment: @Nawaz: It works.  I tried it.  It compiles.  I used it in a program.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I still feel it's not legal.

Comment: @Nawaz: Your feelings are irrelevant.  This is part of the C++ language.  When I say "I used it in a program" I am not talking about a test program, but rather a finished application which was delivered.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Just because something compiled and ran does not mean that it "works". It could mean that you got away with something on that particular compiler.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Just because it works, doesn't mean *"This is part of the C++ language"* (as you claimed).  Quote from the spec to support your claim. (As for your it-works-argument, even this works: http://ideone.com/nLrPU .. but it clearly is undefined behaviour according to the spec).

Comment: This really works... however @Nawaz was right! It seems somehow dirty.

Comment: @Nawaz: I quote from the relevent specs pretty often on this site, but it's a lot of work and I don't feel the need to do it for something as mundane as using `static_cast` on a member function pointers.  You can get this stuff out of any old C++ textbook (well, at least the two I looked at).  Of course it's dangerous, it's a POINTER, and of course there are probably better ways to do it in C++11 or otherwise.

Comment: @Nawaz: If you still feel this is nonstandard, feel free to quote the standard yourself.  You only have to quote one or two lines to show something is wrong, but you have to practically quote the whole thing to show a program is correct.

Comment: I have found a solution by myself - have a look at my own answer!

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done with your current `map` as it stands. Think about what would happen if you *could* put a child method into the map. Then you could pull a pointer-to-child-member (masquerading as base) out of the map, call it on a base class instance pointer, and then how would it call a derived class on a base class instance which obviously couldn't work.

Would a polymorphic approach work?

Comment: It is not neccessary to use templates! Any good/suitable approach would be nice.

Comment: I have found a solution by myself - have a look at my own answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yes; stop using member pointers.

The more correct way of doing what you want is to have an event type and an object pointer. So an event fires on a specific object. The event type would be a *non-member* function (or a static member). It would be passed the object pointer. And it would call some actual member function of that object.

Nowadays, the event type could be a `std/boost::function`. However, since the function parameters have to stay the same type for all events, this doesn't really fix your problem. You can't call `SpecificClass::onBar` from a `BaseClass` pointer unless you do a cast to a `SpecificClass`. And the event calling function would not know to do this. So you still can't put `SpecificClass::onBar` in the `std/boost::function` object; you still need some standalone function to do the cast for you.

This all just seems to be a terrible use of polymorphism. Why does `SpecificClass` need to derive from `BaseClass` at all? Can't they just be two unrelated classes?

Comment: Please have a look at my first post where i entered more details.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: That still doesn't explain why `CivicCenter` needs to be a derived class at all. Nor does it change the truth of anything I said.

Comment: The `Location` class should hold the map with the pointers and it stores the `notify` function derived from another interface which applies to every `Location` object which is the reason why i want to derive rather than manually copy&paste these parts. (for generalization)

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: My point is that derive or copy&paste are not your only options.

Comment: Seems i misunderstood your thoughts. May you show me some sample code?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: Sample code for how to fix your problem (as I described above) or sample code for how to not use polymorphism? I can't give you the latter because you didn't really say why you made `CivicCenter` a derived class, rather than just a particular location. What changes about `CivicCenter`'s interface or data in the deriving?

Comment: Specific locations should provide different actions which are not just global ones (they will part of `Location`) eg. `onCheckStats`. A `CivicCenter` should (hardcoded for now; later dynamically setup via XML) provide e.g. `onMountebank`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3839/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-christian-ivicevic)

Comment: I have found a solution by myself - have a look at my own answer!